# looking for a sensor that activates when hit by a certain frequency burst

Tags: led, sensor, frequency

I have a question that may seem silly, but I am only new at this type of thing:  

Is there a sensor that I could connect to an LED (via an integrated circuit of some description, I assume) that would allow the LED to light up when the sensor came into range of a certain frequency?

I would like to run this setup from a 9v battery, if possible.

If this is possible, could I get a parts listing for what I would need for this setup?

### Added:

What i was trying to achieve was a small device that incorporated an led that lit up when it detected a certain frequency/radio wave from another device (possibly a vehicle). Maybe an antenna instead of a sensor might be the go? Not sure yet and I am still very green with this. It was just an idea I had that may be useful for my work environment.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "a certain frequency"? Do you mean a radio wave frequency? A noise of a certain frequency? (In any case, you can start by googling "bandpass filter.") We can give you a more detailed answer once the question is clarified.

Comment: @Kortuk: I did try to give a moderator flag.  I entered a couple sentences of explanation but then when I hit submit, it complained about not having the minimum characters.  I had well more than that.  It also gave me no option to go back and fix whatever it didn't like.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is an [analog phase lock loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop). This is the same type of circuit that will lock into the nearest FM radio station on your car radio. It works via a feedback loop that adjust an oscillator.

You can also look at basic FM radio receiver circuits, and then manually tune the detector frequency to the frequency you're looking for. Instead of taking the output signal and listening to it, you can run it through a power detector (for example, look for a "Schottky diode Power detector") and then compare that (using a comparator) with a preset power level to know whether you detect a signal or not. A simple transistor radio is [detailed here](http://www.somerset.net/arm/fm_only_one_transistor_radio.html). Note that these circuits won't necessarily work on a wide range of RF frequencies, as FM radio only covers ~85MHz - 101Mhz or so.

Answer (score 1):

There are  custom ICs that fill this role - using methods described in some other answers.

(1) One example is the NE567 tone decoder IC. Old and less available than previously but useful.

NE567
 LM567  TI, NatSemi [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm567.pdf) Digikey
 NJM567  New Japan Radio - [datasheet](http://semicon.njr.co.jp/njr/hp/fileDownloadMedia.do?_mediaId=409) Digikey
 BA1604 ROHM [datasheet]  Digikey  (http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Rohm%20PDFs/BA1604(F).pdf)
 XR-567

(2) Another is
  **XR2211** from XR functionally similar, more flexible and potentially powerful. Only slightly harder to set up. All covered in data sheet. - [datasheet](http://www.exar.com/Common/Content/Document.ashx?id=170)

NJM2211 from NJR - [datasheet](http://semicon.njr.co.jp/njr/hp/fileDownloadMedia.do?_mediaId=413) Digikey

---

From the NJM567 - [datasheet](http://semicon.njr.co.jp/njr/hp/fileDownloadMedia.do?_mediaId=409)

[image]

Setup is relatively easy. They say -

Figure 1 shows a typical connection diagram for the 567. For most applications, the following three-step procedure will
be sufficient for choosing the external components R1, C1 C2 and C3.
Figure 1

1. Select R1 and C1 for the desired center frequency. For best temperature stability, R1 should be between 2K and 20K
   ohm, and the combined temperature coefficient of the R1 C1 product should have sufficient stability over the projected
   temperature range to meet the necessary requirements.
2. Select the low pass capacitor, C2, by referring to the Bandwidth versus Input Signal Amplitude graph. If the input
   amplitude variation is known, the appropriate value of fO C2 necessary to give the desired bandwidth may be found.
   Conversely, an area of operation may be selected on this graph and the input level and C2 may be adjusted accordingly.
   For example, constant bandwidth operation requires that input amplitude be above 200mVrms. The bandwidth, as noted
   on the graph, is then controlled solely by the fO C2 product (fO (Hz), C2 (μfd)).
3. The value of C3 is generally non-critical. C3 sets the band edge of a low pass filter which attenuates frequencies outside
   the detection band to eliminate spurious outputs. If C3 is too small, frequencies just outside the detection band will switch the
   output stage on and off at the beat frequency, or the output may pulse on and off during the turn-on transient. If C3 is too
   large, turn-on and turn-off of the output stage will be delayed until the voltage on C3 passes the threshold voltage. (Such
   delay may be desirable to avoid spurious outputs due to transient frequencies.) A typical minimum value for C3 is 2C2.

NE567 is available from 2 (at least) US suppliers - [see here](http://www.findchips.com/avail?part=ne567)

NJM567 from a different two [see here](http://www.findchips.com/avail?part=njm567) with Online Components showing them as in stock from 71 cents US in 1;s -[see here](http://www.onlinecomponents.com/njr_njm567d.html?p=11973746)

[NJR catalog](http://www.onlinecomponents.com/viewer.aspx?p=36&Resource=475319)

NJM567 is available

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, it's certainly possible to detect a given frequency.

A longer answer will depend on what you're trying to do. Do you want to detect a single specific frequency? Do you want to accept any frequency within a range? What kind of signal are you trying to detect?

There are various [parts](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=MC100EP140) that can detect a specific frequency. To get an idea of how they work, read about [phase detectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_detector). On the other hand, if you're interested in detecting all frequencies within a range, use a [band pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-pass_filter).

Comment: A phase detector won't do him much good without an LO and a bunch of other parts to solve his problem. Based on the quality of the question, I doubt if OP is experienced enough to know this himself.

Comment: @ThePhoton No argument there, but *reading* about phase detectors would be a good step toward understanding how such circuits work.